# how to regroup entities having relationship with each other and display them in one page?

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I'm getting started with `jhipster`, 
I create entity "shop" this entity has `OneToMany` relationship with the entity "command"; each "command" has a `OneToMany` relationship with the entity "product" and a `ManyToOne` relationship with the entity "Client". In fact every shop is composed of a group of command, every command is composed of a group of products and every command is associated to a Client. In my application, my goal is to display in one page the details of a shop, the list of all products and the client that commanded every product. For the moment I generated my entities but I don't know how to start specially that it is the first time that I used `jhipster`.
 All ideas are welcome.
 Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  - refer this before posting a query . Opinion based querys will get closed quickly in stackoverflow

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to show your efforts...

Comment: My problem is that  I didn't know how to start ; I just need someone to guide me, so sorry but i'm a beginner

Comment: JHipster is not really a tool for beginners. You are supposed to know already Spring Boot and JPA/Hibernate, you can begin with Angular but at least you should know the server stack.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the resources generated by JHipster return  only the root objects.

For instance, `ShopResource` returns only Shop objects without their linked list of `Product` because the generator does not know what you want to do with it so it takes a minimal approach: the relationships between entities are lazy-loaded.

So first thing is to make sure that your related objects are loaded by ShopResource, have a look at your entities annotations. Learn about JPA/Hibenrnate.

Once you are sure related entities are loaded, they should be serialized in JSON, you can check this in the API docs menu of JHipster which uses swagger-ui.

Then, create your view and controller in angular and you should be able to refer to linked objects using `shop.products` notation.